# Can an Alchemist turn a Coven member into an Acolyte?

Tags: werewolv.es

Title says it all. The h2p implies it is possible to become an Acolyte, but I doubt this is really the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, Acolyte is not in the possible list of roles that the Alchemist can turn a Coven member into.